Edit question with minor typo
I just answered this question and found a typo within the definition of the $CF_j$ formula. I wanted to edit the question and correct the typo, which is essentially for the subsequent math and the understanding of the formula. However, i get this warning:

Edits must be at least 6 characters; is there something else to improve in this post?

How should we correct typos within formulas, which are typically less than six characters but of high importance for the math?

You can either improve the question further by changing more, notify the OP as I don't think the limit holds for the OP or note it in your answer (sometimes the question arises because of problems with notation).
